# Doctrine Order by id=1

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by

I want get list users and current user must be first every-time.
In MySql i can make as:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY id = 2 DESC
```

In Doctrine i try make alike:

```
 $query = $this->_em->createQuery("SELECT bul, u, c FROM 'Building\Entity\BuildingUserLink' bul JOIN bul.building b JOIN bul.company c JOIN bul.user u WHERE b = :building_id ORDER BY u.id = :current_id DESC");
 $query->setParameters(array('building_id' => $building_id, 'current_id' => $current_id));
 return $query->getResult();
```

But i get error - "Expected end of string, got \u0027=\u0027\"

What is my fault?

PS I used ZF2+DOctrine

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY id = 2 DESC, id DESC
```

In your actual query:

```
ORDER BY u.id = :current_id DESC, u.id DESC
```

Comment: Its not work for me. I have error againe:
Error: Expected end of string, got '='\n#0 /host/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(448):.....

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the FIELD function in MySQL. Support for the FIELD function can be added to doctrine using https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions.

The query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2) DESC
```